# Migrating add image to pdf from iText to PDFBox

Tags: itext, pdfbox

In our project we are using iText 5.x version to manipulate PDF files and working to migrate that implementation with PDFBox 2.x version.

There is one add image to pdf page scenario and I have converted that code into PDFBox as good as I could do. :)  In existing implementation(iText) they add image in template using PdfTemplate and added that template in annotation using PdfAnnotation class.

I don't know how to do that using PDFBox. Also please check that I migrated existing implementation properly or not as I'm newbie in PDF library using Java.

**Add Image to PDF(Using iText):**

```
Document document = null;
        PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(SourceFilePath());        
        
        //we retrieve the total number of pages and the page size
        int total = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
        Rectangle rectangle = pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        
        document = new Document(rectangle);
        PdfImportedPage page;
        PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;
        
        // step 2: we create a PdfCopy object that listens to the document.
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(DestinationFilePath(false)); 
        
        document.open();
        
     // step 4: adding the content
        for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            page = copy.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
            if(i == 1 || aBarcodeVO.getDisplacementVO().isApplyForAllPages()){
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = getImage();
                
                Image img =  Image.getInstance(bufferedImage, null);
                img.scaleToFit(qrImageSize, qrImageSize);
    
                PdfName imgKey = new PdfName(aBarcodeVO.getImgUniqueId() + i);
                Rectangle rectPage = pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);
                
                stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
    
                PdfImage stream = new PdfImage(img, "", null);
                stream.put(imgKey, imgKey);
                PdfIndirectObject ref = copy.addToBody(stream);
                
                int rotation = pdfReader.getPageRotation(i);
                Rectangle cropBoxRect = pdfReader.getCropBox(i);;
    
             
                
              //Explicitly Apply rotation to crop box rectangle. 
                for (int j = 0; j < (rotation/90); j++) {
                    cropBoxRect = cropBoxRect.rotate();
                }
                
                
                
                //added Image in template and template in Annotation and finally annotation is added in PDF through PdfCopy.PageStamp
                PdfTemplate template = PdfTemplate.createTemplate(copy, img.getPlainWidth(), img.getPlainHeight());
                img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                img.setRotationDegrees(rotation);
                img.setDirectReference(ref.getIndirectReference());
                template.addImage(img);
    
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(rectLlx, rectLly, rectUrx, rectUry);
                rect.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
                rect.setBorderColor(new BaseColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
                
                PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createStamp(copy, rect, null, "AnnotationOnly");
                annotation.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, template);
                annotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT + PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED);
                annotation.setRotate(rotation);
                PdfName annotKey = getAnnotKey(i);
                annotation.put(annotKey, annotKey);
                stamp.addAnnotation(annotation); 
                stamp.alterContents();
            }
            copy.addPage(page);
        }
        copy.freeReader(pdfReader);
        
        try {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in handleAddBarCode() while closing():document:" + e);
        }
        try {
            if (pdfReader != null) {
                pdfReader.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in handleAddBarCode() while closing():pdfReader:" + e);
        }
```

**Add Image to PDF(Using PDFBox):**

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(SourceFilePath()));
int total = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();

PDPage page = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
PDRectangle rectangle = getRotatedMediaBox(page);

PDPage pdPage = new PDPage(rectangle);
PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    pdPage = newDocument.importPage(pdDocument.getPage(i));
    PDRectangle pageRect = getRotatedMediaBox(pdPage);
    
    int rotation = pdPage.getRotation();
    
    PDRectangle cropBoxRect =  page.getCropBox();
    
    //Calculate margin between crop box rectangle and page rectangle.
    float[] margins = getCropBoxMargin(pageRect, cropBoxRect, rotation);
    
    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
        cropBoxRect = new PDRectangle(cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftY(), cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftX(), cropBoxRect.getHeight(),
                cropBoxRect.getWidth());
    }
    
    
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = getImage();
    PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
            PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
    PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(newDocument, bufferedImage);
    
    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
        Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation), 0, 0);
        PDRectangle cropBox = pdPage.getCropBox();
        float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
        float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;

        Rectangle rectang = cropBox.transform(matrix).getBounds();
        float scale = Math.min(cropBox.getWidth() / (float)rectang.getWidth(), cropBox.getHeight() / (float)rectang.getHeight());

        pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
        pageContentStream.transform(matrix);
        pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
        pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
    }
    
    pageContentStream.drawImage(image, rectLlx, rectLly, qrImageSize, qrImageSize);
    pageContentStream.close();
}
newDocument.save(new File(DestinationFilePath(false)));

newDocument.close();
pdDocument.close();
```

Please help me on this or at least looking forward for your suggestions for code needs to rectify of PDFBox implementation.

Comment: It is generally much harder to get things done using Apache PDFBox versus using the iText library.  You should tell us exactly what is wrong with your PDFBox code so that we know what to look for.

Comment: In contrast to your itext solution your pdfbox solution puts the image into the page content instead of an annotation. Is that OK?

Comment: @mkl So Is that possible to achieve same using PDFBox?(To put image into annotation) Or it is not mandatory to do so.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen By my code what I meant to ask is that PDFBox implementation make any behavioral difference compare to iText implementation?

Comment: *"So Is that possible to achieve same using PDFBox?(To put image into annotation)"* - yes, probably a bit more verbose than with iText. *"Or it is not mandatory to do so"* - that depends on what the code is specified to do.

Comment: The RubberStampWithImage.java example from the source code download may help. But if you have working itext code, why bother with PDFBox? Did you check whether the development costs are lower than the licensing costs? Or does itext use a licensing model where you're paying for each PDF?

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Thanks for your suggestion. **It will help me.** About licensing cost, I am not really aware whether its costing per PDF but the main reason we are moving is that PDFBox is open source and iText is not.

Comment: @Asite I am wondering a bit why the iText guys didn't already jump at your last answer. So lets put this right: iText is *open source* since the source code is publicly available: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf But what you probably wanted to say is: The license is different. iText is using AGPL and PdfBox is using Apache 2.0. Especially in a commercial setting you can not use AGPL but Apache licences.